# otbr-agent with NRF52840 as RCP not working

Tags: openthread

I am using custom linux board and taken latest code of otbr-agent.
Also taken latest code of ot-nrf528xx for NRF52840.

otbr-agent is able to communicate with RCP successfully and my openthread network is created as well.
But randomly it files following error and exits:

> otbr-agent[14116]: 00:35:22.736 [WARN]-PLAT----: radio tx timeout
> otbr-agent[14116]: 00:35:22.736 [CRIT]-PLAT----: HandleRcpTimeout() at
> /usr/src/debug/otbr/git-r0/ot-br-posix/third_party/openthread/repo/src/lib/spinel
> /radio_spinel_impl.hpp:2218: RadioSpinelNoResponse

Full logs of otbr-agent from start are as below and it was exited without any activity.
Once I was able to commission and communicate with device and after it got exited with same error.
Is it issue from otbr? or rcp?

```
#/usr/sbin/otbr-agent -I wpan0 -B wlan0 spinel+hdlc+uart:///dev/ttymxc0 trel://wlan0 -v
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-UTILS---: Running 0.3.0-fe1263578-dirty
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-UTILS---: Thread version: 1.2.0
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-UTILS---: Thread interface: wpan0
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-UTILS---: Backbone interface: wlan0
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-UTILS---: Radio URL: spinel+hdlc+uart:///dev/ttymxc0
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-UTILS---: Radio URL: trel://wlan0
otbr-agent[14116]: 49d.18:38:21.580 [INFO]-PLAT----: RCP reset: RESET_POWER_ON
otbr-agent[14116]: 49d.18:38:21.609 [NOTE]-PLAT----: RCP API Version: 5
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.073 [INFO]-CORE----: [settings] Read NetworkInfo {rloc:0xe000, extaddr:ae12db553a8f7115, role:leader, mode:0x0f, version:3, 
keyseq:0x0, ...
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.075 [INFO]-CORE----: [settings] ... pid:0x54beb0f8, mlecntr:0x1f9ed, maccntr:0x1f7f2, mliid:7c75ca665c72a43b}
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.146 [INFO]-CORE----: [settings] Read OmrPrefix fd7a:10e5:333a:5b12::/64
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.150 [INFO]-CORE----: [settings] Read OnLinkPrefix fd2f:7c27:62f6:0::/64
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.158 [INFO]-BR------: Infra interface (7) state changed: NOT RUNNING -> RUNNING
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-AGENT---: Set state callback: OK
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.159 [INFO]-SRP-----: [server] selected port 53535
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.173 [INFO]-N-DATA--: Publisher: Publishing DNS/SRP service unicast (ml-eid, port:53535)
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.174 [INFO]-N-DATA--: Publisher: DNS/SRP service - State: NoEntry -> ToAdd
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-AGENT---: Stop Thread Border Agent
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-ADPROXY-: Stopped
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-AGENT---: Initialize OpenThread Border Router Agent: OK
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-UTILS---: Border router agent started.
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.202 [INFO]-CORE----: Notifier: StateChanged (0x101fc300) [KeySeqCntr NetData Channel PanId NetName ExtPanId NetworkKey PSKc 
SecPolicy ...
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.213 [INFO]-CORE----: Notifier: StateChanged (0x101fc300) ... ActDset]
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.214 [INFO]-MLE-----: [announce-sender] ChannelMask:{ 11-26 }, period:21500
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.214 [INFO]-MLE-----: [announce-sender] StartingChannel:18
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.222 [INFO]-MLE-----: [announce-sender] StartingChannel:18
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.250 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Host netif is down
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.262 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Added multicast address ff02::1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.262 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Added multicast address ff03::1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.263 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Added multicast address ff03::fc
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.281 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Sent request#1 to add fe80::ac12:db55:3a8f:7115/64
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.282 [NOTE]-MLE-----: Role disabled -> detached
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.297 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Sent request#2 to add fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:7c75:ca66:5c72:a43b/64
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.313 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Added multicast address ff32:40:fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.313 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Added multicast address ff33:40:fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.323 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Sent request#3 to add fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:ff:fe00:e000/64
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.323 [INFO]-MLE-----: Attempt to become router
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.325 [INFO]-CORE----: [settings] Read NetworkInfo {rloc:0xe000, extaddr:ae12db553a8f7115, role:leader, mode:0x0f, version:3, 
keyseq:0x0, ...
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.327 [INFO]-CORE----: [settings] ... pid:0x54beb0f8, mlecntr:0x1f9ed, maccntr:0x1f7f2, mliid:7c75ca665c72a43b}
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.337 [INFO]-CORE----: [settings] Saved NetworkInfo {rloc:0xe000, extaddr:ae12db553a8f7115, role:leader, mode:0x0f, version:3,
 keyseq:0x0, ...
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.345 [INFO]-CORE----: [settings] ... pid:0x54beb0f8, mlecntr:0x1fdd6, maccntr:0x1fbda, mliid:7c75ca665c72a43b}
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.345 [INFO]-MLE-----: Send Link Request (ff02:0:0:0:0:0:0:2)
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.345 [INFO]-CORE----: Notifier: StateChanged (0x0100103d) [Ip6+ Role LLAddr MLAddr Rloc+ Ip6Mult+ NetifState]
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.353 [INFO]-MLE-----: [announce-sender] Stopped
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.354 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Changing interface state to up.
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-AGENT---: Thread is down
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-AGENT---: Stop Thread Border Agent
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-ADPROXY-: Stopped
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.475 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Failed to transmit, error:Drop
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.539 [INFO]-CORE----: Notifier: StateChanged (0x00001000) [Ip6Mult+]
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.551 [INFO]-PLAT----: [trel] Interface address added successfully.
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.607 [INFO]-MAC-----: Sent IPv6 UDP msg, len:82, chksum:51e5, to:0xffff, sec:no, prio:net, radio:all
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.626 [INFO]-MAC-----:     src:[fe80:0:0:0:ac12:db55:3a8f:7115]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.626 [INFO]-MAC-----:     dst:[ff02:0:0:0:0:0:0:2]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.645 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] ADD [U] fe80::ac12:db55:3a8f:7115 (already subscribed, ignored)
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.646 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Unexpected address type (6).
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.646 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Unexpected address type (8).
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.674 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Succeeded to process request#1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.714 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] ADD [U] fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:7c75:ca66:5c72:a43b (already subscribed, ignored)
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.714 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Unexpected address type (6).
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.715 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Unexpected address type (8).
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.760 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Failed to transmit, error:Drop
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.760 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Succeeded to process request#2
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.824 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff02::1:3
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.824 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] ADD [U] fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:ff:fe00:e000 (already subscribed, ignored)
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.825 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Unexpected address type (6).
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.825 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Unexpected address type (8).
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.825 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Succeeded to process request#3
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:00.825 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Host netif is up
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:01.220 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Failed to transmit, error:Drop
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:01.222 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff02::1:3
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:01.222 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff33:40:fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:01.223 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff32:40:fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:01.223 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff03::fc
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:01.223 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff03::1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:01.223 [INFO]-CORE----: Notifier: StateChanged (0x00001000) [Ip6Mult+]
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:02.157 [NOTE]-MLE-----: RLOC16 e000 -> fffe
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:02.163 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Sent request#4 to remove fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:ff:fe00:e000/64
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:02.165 [INFO]-MLE-----: AttachState Idle -> Start
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:02.166 [INFO]-CORE----: Notifier: StateChanged (0x10000040) [Rloc- ActDset]
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:02.181 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] DEL [U] fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:ff:fe00:e000 (not found, ignored)
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:02.181 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Unexpected address type (6).
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:02.181 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Unexpected address type (8).
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:02.182 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Succeeded to process request#4
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:02.413 [NOTE]-MLE-----: Attempt to attach - attempt 1, any-partition reattaching with Active Dataset
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:02.413 [INFO]-MLE-----: AttachState Start -> ParentReqRouters
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:02.414 [INFO]-MLE-----: Send Parent Request to routers (ff02:0:0:0:0:0:0:2)
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:02.433 [INFO]-MAC-----: Sent IPv6 UDP msg, len:84, chksum:503d, to:0xffff, sec:no, prio:net, radio:all
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:02.434 [INFO]-MAC-----:     src:[fe80:0:0:0:ac12:db55:3a8f:7115]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:02.434 [INFO]-MAC-----:     dst:[ff02:0:0:0:0:0:0:2]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:03.164 [INFO]-MLE-----: AttachState ParentReqRouters -> ParentReqReeds
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:03.164 [INFO]-MLE-----: Send Parent Request to routers and REEDs (ff02:0:0:0:0:0:0:2)
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:03.183 [INFO]-MAC-----: Sent IPv6 UDP msg, len:84, chksum:3d1a, to:0xffff, sec:no, prio:net, radio:all
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:03.183 [INFO]-MAC-----:     src:[fe80:0:0:0:ac12:db55:3a8f:7115]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:03.183 [INFO]-MAC-----:     dst:[ff02:0:0:0:0:0:0:2]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.415 [INFO]-MLE-----: AttachState ParentReqReeds -> Idle
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.416 [NOTE]-MLE-----: Allocate router id 56
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.416 [NOTE]-MLE-----: RLOC16 fffe -> e000
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.427 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Sent request#5 to add fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:ff:fe00:e000/64
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.428 [NOTE]-MLE-----: Role detached -> leader
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.449 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Sent request#6 to add fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:ff:fe00:fc00/64
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.452 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Added multicast address ff02::2
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.453 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Added multicast address ff03::2
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.459 [NOTE]-MLE-----: Leader partition id 0x6f7040fb
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.459 [INFO]-CORE----: Notifier: StateChanged (0x100012a5) [Ip6+ Role Rloc+ PartitionId NetData Ip6Mult+ ActDset]
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.461 [INFO]-MLE-----: Send Data Response (ff02:0:0:0:0:0:0:1)
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.461 [INFO]-BBR-----: PBBR state: None
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.463 [INFO]-BBR-----: Domain Prefix: ::/0, state: None
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.473 [INFO]-CORE----: [settings] Saved NetworkInfo {rloc:0xe000, extaddr:ae12db553a8f7115, role:leader, mode:0x0f, version:3,
 keyseq:0x0, ...
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.474 [INFO]-CORE----: [settings] ... pid:0x6f7040fb, mlecntr:0x1fdd9, maccntr:0x1fbda, mliid:7c75ca665c72a43b}
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.474 [INFO]-MLE-----: [announce-sender] Started
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.480 [INFO]-MESH-CP-: Border Agent start listening on port 0
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.481 [INFO]-BR------: Border Routing manager started
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.481 [INFO]-BR------: Start Router Solicitation, scheduled in 803 milliseconds
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.481 [INFO]-BR------: Start evaluating routing policy, scheduled in 162 milliseconds
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.481 [INFO]-N-DATA--: Publisher: DNS/SRP service (state:ToAdd) in netdata - total:0, preferred:0, desired:2
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.481 [INFO]-N-DATA--: Publisher: DNS/SRP service - State: ToAdd -> Adding
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.482 [INFO]-N-DATA--: Publisher: DNS/SRP service (state:Adding) - update in 2270 msec
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-AGENT---: Thread is up
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-AGENT---: Stop Thread Border Agent
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-ADPROXY-: Stopped
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-ADPROXY-: Started
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-MDNS----: Avahi client state changed to 2.
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-MDNS----: Avahi client ready.
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-AGENT---: Publish meshcop service OpenThread Border Router._meshcop._udp.local.
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-MDNS----: Avahi group change to state 0.
otbr-agent[14116]: [ERR ]-MDNS----: Group ready.
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-MDNS----: Create service OpenThread Border Router._meshcop._udp for host localhost
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-MDNS----: Commit service OpenThread Border Router._meshcop._udp
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-ADPROXY-: Publish all hosts and services
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-AGENT---: Start Thread Border Agent: OK
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.683 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] ADD [U] fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:ff:fe00:e000 (already subscribed, ignored)
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.684 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Unexpected address type (6).
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.684 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Unexpected address type (8).
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.695 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Failed to transmit, error:Drop
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.695 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Succeeded to process request#5
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.697 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff03::2
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.697 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff02::2
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.697 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff02::1:3
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.701 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff33:40:fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.701 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff32:40:fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.701 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff03::fc
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.706 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff03::1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.707 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff02::16
otbr-agent[14116]: [INFO]-MDNS----: Avahi group change to state 1.
otbr-agent[14116]: [ERR ]-MDNS----: Group ready.
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.710 [INFO]-BR------: Evaluating routing policy
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.716 [INFO]-BR------: EvaluateOmrPrefix: No valid OMR prefixes found in Thread network
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.720 [INFO]-N-DATA--: Sent server data notification
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.720 [INFO]-BR------: Published local OMR prefix fd7a:10e5:333a:5b12::/64 in Thread network
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.727 [INFO]-BR------: Send OMR prefix fd7a:10e5:333a:5b12::/64 in RIO (valid lifetime = 1800 seconds)
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.729 [INFO]-BR------: Sent Router Advertisement on interface 7
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.730 [INFO]-BR------: Router advertisement scheduled in 16 seconds
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.731 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Failed to transmit, error:Drop
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.737 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] ADD [U] fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:ff:fe00:fc00 (already subscribed, ignored)
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.737 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Unexpected address type (6).
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.737 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Unexpected address type (8).
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.740 [INFO]-N-DATA--: Received network data registration
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.741 [INFO]-N-DATA--: Allocated Context ID = 1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.742 [INFO]-N-DATA--: Sent network data registration acknowledgment
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.743 [INFO]-BR------: Received Router Advertisement from fe80:0:0:0:ac12:db55:3a8f:7115 on interface 7
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.763 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Succeeded to process request#6
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.772 [INFO]-CORE----: Notifier: StateChanged (0x00000200) [NetData]
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.772 [INFO]-MLE-----: Send Data Response (ff02:0:0:0:0:0:0:1)
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.772 [INFO]-BBR-----: PBBR state: None
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.773 [INFO]-BBR-----: Domain Prefix: ::/0, state: None
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.773 [INFO]-CORE----: [settings] Read SlaacIidSecretKey
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.773 [INFO]-UTIL----: SLAAC: Adding address fd7a:10e5:333a:5b12:572a:d02a:e7fb:a8ec
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.792 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Sent request#7 to add fd7a:10e5:333a:5b12:572a:d02a:e7fb:a8ec/64
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.793 [INFO]-BR------: Start evaluating routing policy, scheduled in 191 milliseconds
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.793 [INFO]-N-DATA--: Publisher: DNS/SRP service (state:Adding) in netdata - total:0, preferred:0, desired:2
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.799 [INFO]-MAC-----: Sent IPv6 UDP msg, len:96, chksum:bf39, to:0xffff, sec:no, prio:net, radio:all
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.799 [INFO]-MAC-----:     src:[fe80:0:0:0:ac12:db55:3a8f:7115]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.799 [INFO]-MAC-----:     dst:[ff02:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.802 [INFO]-CORE----: Notifier: StateChanged (0x00000001) [Ip6+]
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.818 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Failed to transmit, error:Drop
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.819 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] ADD [U] fd7a:10e5:333a:5b12:572a:d02a:e7fb:a8ec (already subscribed, ignored)
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.819 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Unexpected address type (6).
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.822 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Unexpected address type (8).
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.839 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff03::2
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.840 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff02::2
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.841 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff02::1:3
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.842 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff33:40:fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.843 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff32:40:fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.848 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff03::fc
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.849 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff03::1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.849 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff02::16
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.852 [INFO]-PLAT----: [netif] Succeeded to process request#7
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.872 [INFO]-MAC-----: Sent IPv6 UDP msg, len:118, chksum:b222, to:0xffff, sec:no, prio:net, radio:all
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.872 [INFO]-MAC-----:     src:[fe80:0:0:0:ac12:db55:3a8f:7115]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:04.872 [INFO]-MAC-----:     dst:[ff02:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.207 [INFO]-BR------: Evaluating routing policy
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.208 [INFO]-BR------: Send OMR prefix fd7a:10e5:333a:5b12::/64 in RIO (valid lifetime = 1800 seconds)
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.210 [INFO]-BR------: Sent Router Advertisement on interface 7
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.210 [INFO]-BR------: Router advertisement scheduled in 16 seconds
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.211 [INFO]-BR------: Received Router Advertisement from fe80:0:0:0:ac12:db55:3a8f:7115 on interface 7
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.284 [INFO]-BR------: Router solicitation times out
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.381 [INFO]-MLE-----: Send Advertisement (ff02:0:0:0:0:0:0:1)
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.399 [INFO]-MAC-----: Sent IPv6 UDP msg, len:90, chksum:83f4, to:0xffff, sec:no, prio:net, radio:all
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.405 [INFO]-MAC-----:     src:[fe80:0:0:0:ac12:db55:3a8f:7115]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.409 [INFO]-MAC-----:     dst:[ff02:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.540 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Failed to transmit, error:Drop
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.558 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff03::2
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.573 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff02::2
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.573 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff02::1:3
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.573 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff33:40:fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.574 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff32:40:fd5d:e08d:c5ec:42fc:0:1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.580 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff03::fc
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.580 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff03::1
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:00:05.581 [NOTE]-PLAT----: [netif] Will not subscribe duplicate multicast address ff02::16
.
.
.
.
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:34:30.334 [INFO]-MAC-----: Sent IPv6 UDP msg, len:90, chksum:a5b1, to:0xffff, sec:no, prio:net, radio:all
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:34:30.335 [INFO]-MAC-----:     src:[fe80:0:0:0:ac12:db55:3a8f:7115]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:34:30.338 [INFO]-MAC-----:     dst:[ff02:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:34:34.259 [INFO]-MLE-----: Send Announce on channel 21
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:34:34.281 [INFO]-MAC-----: Sent IPv6 UDP msg, len:83, chksum:9a63, to:0xffff, sec:yes, prio:net, radio:all
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:34:34.282 [INFO]-MAC-----:     src:[fe80:0:0:0:ac12:db55:3a8f:7115]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:34:34.282 [INFO]-MAC-----:     dst:[ff02:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:34:55.946 [INFO]-MLE-----: Send Announce on channel 22
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:34:55.971 [INFO]-MAC-----: Sent IPv6 UDP msg, len:83, chksum:3dc6, to:0xffff, sec:yes, prio:net, radio:all
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:34:55.972 [INFO]-MAC-----:     src:[fe80:0:0:0:ac12:db55:3a8f:7115]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:34:55.972 [INFO]-MAC-----:     dst:[ff02:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:35:02.159 [WARN]-PLAT----: [netif] Failed to transmit, error:Drop
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:35:12.789 [INFO]-MLE-----: Send Advertisement (ff02:0:0:0:0:0:0:1)
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:35:12.807 [INFO]-MAC-----: Sent IPv6 UDP msg, len:90, chksum:daa6, to:0xffff, sec:no, prio:net, radio:all
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:35:12.814 [INFO]-MAC-----:     src:[fe80:0:0:0:ac12:db55:3a8f:7115]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:35:12.814 [INFO]-MAC-----:     dst:[ff02:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:19788
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:35:17.734 [INFO]-MLE-----: Send Announce on channel 23
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:35:22.736 [WARN]-PLAT----: radio tx timeout
otbr-agent[14116]: 00:35:22.736 [CRIT]-PLAT----: HandleRcpTimeout() at /usr/src/debug/otbr/git-r0/ot-br-posix/third_party/openthread/repo/src/lib/spinel
/radio_spinel_impl.hpp:2218: RadioSpinelNoResponse
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the prints are coming from the OTBR application. The reason for the bug is a problem in communications between your OTBR app and the RCP.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).